# User Name in Spring Send Mail API

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

How to pass the different user name instead of displaying the from email name in mail received to the end user java send mail API.

Comment: I suggest checking the [javadoc](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html) of `InternetAddress`. Or [rfc822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) which specifies the format.

Answer (score 0):

Atleast you can google first for your question. Anyways refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm).

Comment: my intention was on how to send user friendly from name through spring mailer api. For example if you have from = test@gmail.com in the recieved mail test will be displayed as user name but i need to pass name of my own like 123